# Should directory access be taken care of by models or controllers?

Tags: model-view-controller, directory

I have an app that requires adding and deleting image files in a simple interface. Should the controller be the one that directly deletes these files, or should deleting files be in the domain of my models?

I ask because files could be viewed as a type of "data". Just want to know what the convention is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your models are designed, but overall I think it's model's matter.

This is because even if adding / deleting is just a plain filesystem actions wrapper right now, it may involve database actions / revision support in the future: this way the controller is agnostic to what really happens.

```
for f in filesToDelete:

    f.delete();

endfor;
```

Where `delete` could be:

```
public function delete()
{

    unlink(this.path);

}
```

or

```
public function delete()
{

    db::remove(this.path);  // or whatever

    unlink(this.path);

}
```

And if you need batch operations, you just model a `Folder` / `SmartFolder` class in order to perform them.